# Qt6 and Multimedia module

Tags: qt, qtmultimedia, qt6

As I can see in Qt6 no more Multimedia API. Am I right? Is it correct that in Qt6 for such simple task as playing sound I should look at third-party libraries now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Qt6 is a big change so for compatibility reasons Qt does not provide this module, it will be provided in Qt 6.2 as this post: [Add-on support in Qt 6.0 and beyond](https://www.qt.io/blog/add-on-support-in-qt-6.0-and-beyond) points out, so if you want to reproduce sounds you will have to use a third party library.

> For Qt 6.2 we are planning to provide the following additional
> libraries:
>
> - Qt Bluetooth
> - Qt Data Visualization
> - Qt Lottie Animation
> - **Qt Multimedia**
> - Qt NFC
> - Qt Positioning
> - Qt Quick Dialogs: Folder, Message Box
> - Qt Remote Objects
> - Qt Sensors
> - Qt SerialBus
> - Qt SerialPort
> - Qt WebChannel
> - Qt WebEngine
> - Qt WebSockets
> - Qt WebView

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Qt Multimedia is (again) part of [Qt 6.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-index.html).

Note though that the module was undergoing a substantial rewrite. For more details, see e.g. https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-multimedia-in-qt-6 and the relevant [porting documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-changes-qt6.html).