# How to install Qt with multimedia on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtmultimedia

I'd installed QT for Windows but when I try to use
`QT += multimedia` in the .pro file it showed me that this module was unknown. I checked Qt online installer for additional modules but there was no such a component there. How can I get Qt with multimedia on Windows?

Comment: I build from source but use Qt5. Not sure if you are using Qt6. If you are this may be the issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213872/qt6-and-multimedia-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213872/qt6-and-multimedia-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Qt 6, Qt multimedia will be re-provided in Qt 6.2 which hasn't been released yet. You can find the whole list of modules which will be added to Qt 6.2 here:
https://www.qt.io/blog/add-on-support-in-qt-6.0-and-beyond

```
For Qt 6.2 we are planning to provide the following additional libraries:

 Qt Bluetooth
 Qt Data Visualization
 Qt Lottie Animation
 Qt Multimedia
 Qt NFC
 Qt Positioning
 Qt Quick Dialogs: Folder, Message Box
 Qt Remote Objects
 Qt Sensors
 Qt SerialBus
 Qt SerialPort
 Qt WebChannel
 Qt WebEngine
 Qt WebSockets
 Qt WebView
```